# Generating a sound using two channel in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, audio, audio-processing

I am trying to create a sound using two channels. I send two signals with different frequencies.

I am trying to do it without the *Data Acquisition Toolbox*. It is possible to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could resample the two signal to the same sampling frequency, combine them as matrix columns, then create a WAVE file using the `wavwrite` function (or play the sound directly with `soundsc`)